# Don't get the glob function in PHP

Tags: php, filesystems

[http://php.net/glob](https://www.php.net/glob)

The documentation page on glob() has this example:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```

But to be honest, I don't understand how this can work.

The array produced by glob("*.txt") will be traversed, but where does this array come from? Is glob() reading a directory? I don't see that anywhere in the code. Glob() looks for all matches to *.txt

But where do you set where the glob() function should look for these strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any directory specified glob() would act on the current working directory (often the same directory as the script, but not always).

To make it more useful, use a full path such as glob("/var/log/*.log"). Admittedly the PHP documentation doesn't make the behaviour clear, but glob() is a [C library function](http://man.cx/glob(3posix)), which is where it originates from.

Answer (score 2):

Something useful I've discovered with `glob()`, if you want to traverse a directory, for example, for images, but want to match more than one file extension, examine this code.

```
 $images = glob($imagesDir . '*' . '.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

The `GLOB_BRACE` flag makes the braces sort of work like the `(a|b)` regex.

One small caveat is that you need to list them out, so you can't use regex syntax such as `jpe?g` to match `jpg` or `jpeg`.

Comment: How would you use this to exclude (e.g. `{^jpeg,jpg}` )?

Comment: @jdborg You wouldn't, you'd need to `array_filter()` the results from `glob()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, glob reads the directory.  Therefore, if you are looking to match files in a specific directory, then the argument you supply to glob() should be specific enough to point out the directory (ie "/my/dir/*.png").  Otherwise, I believe that it will search for files in the 'current' directory.

Note that on some systems filenames can be case-sensitive so "*.png" may not find files ending in ".PNG".

A [general overview of its purpose can be found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).  Its functionality in PHP is based on that of the [libc glob function](http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/doc/devel-guide/src/lib/glibc-glob.c.html) whose rationale can be read at http://web.archive.org/web/20071219090708/http://www.isc.org/sources/devel/func/glob.txt .